# Changing the PHP memory limit in settings.php is not reflected in phpinfo()

Tags: 7

Of the various methods to increase the PHP memory limit, the only one I can use for a certain site is `ini_set('memory_limit', 'XXXM');` in settings.php.

This value does not appear to change the memory_limit shown in phpinfo(). However, I know it is actually being modified because the site breaks without it.

Is there another way to view the current memory limit OR the actual memory limit ceiling?

Comment: You are probably calling phpinfo() before settings.php. What if you use the built-in phpinfo() linked in the Status Report? /admin/reports/status/php

Comment: Also, some hosts may not allow you to change it above a certain amount.

Comment: @4uk4 that's a great comment, can you pls put it as proper answer so I can tick it etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably calling phpinfo() before settings.php. What if you use the built-in phpinfo() linked in the Status Report?

http://www.example.com/admin/reports/status/php